# Elixir, replace some values in list 1 with values from list 2

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Given two lists x and y, both are same length

```
list x
[[], ["replaceTwo"], [], ["replaceFour"], []]

list y
[["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"], ["five"]]
```

how can I create another list which has the values of list x but in the case of the value being an empty list, it should have the value from list y for that very same index?

like so

```
list z =[["one"], ["replaceTwo"], ["three"], ["replaceFour"], ["five"]]
```

Comment: Could you double check your syntax? These aren't lists. Are they lists of lists? Should there be square brackets surrounding all of the lists? e.g. `[[], ["replaceTwo"], [], ["replaceFour"], []]`

Comment: @sbacarob yes lists of list, added brackets

Answer (score 3):

You can use Enum.zip to unite the lists and then Enum.map with pattern matching to grab elements from the second list when the element from the first one is an empty list, like this:

```
defmodule Example do
  def unite_and_replace(list1, list2) do
    list1
    |> Enum.zip(list2)
    |> Enum.map(fn {[], list2_element} -> list2_element
                   {list1_element, _} -> list1_element end)
  end
end

iex(1)> list1 = [[], ["replaceTwo"], [], ["replaceFour"], []]
iex(2)> list2 = [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"], ["five"]]

iex(3)> Example.unite_and_replace list1, list2
[["one"], ["replaceTwo"], ["three"], ["replaceFour"], ["five"]]
```